# Support with joining to tables.(New to Oracle Apex)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Hi basically I am trying to join the customer Name column over to the contract column using the code below. But it gives me an error which I don't understand.

The error:

```
Region → Contract → Source → SQL Query ORA-06550: line 5, column 28: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

The SQL:

```
select CONTRACT_NO,
       CUSTOMER_CODE,
       START_DATE,
       END_DATE
  from CONTRACT INNER JOIN CUSTOMER
ON Contract.code = Customer.name
```

[[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to post another image. It replaces what I have. But the other image basically contains the contract table. And it has the following columns:                                Contract No, Customer Code Start Date and End date.  I

Comment: So what is the error?

Comment: Region → Contract → Source → SQL Query
ORA-06550: line 5, column 28: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist. This is what it says.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want the current columns and also a column for name from another table.

```
select co.CONTRACT_NO,
       co.CUSTOMER_CODE,
       co.START_DATE,
       co.END_DATE,
       cu.name
  from CONTRACT co
 INNER JOIN CUSTOMER cu
    ON co.code = cu.name;
```

This looks like code that ought to work, but you need to check that all the columns exist in the table you need them, and that co.code and cu.name actually do have the same values.

And also, for future questions, the tag is oracle-apex, I changed it for you this time. The apex tag is a different unrelated thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a space in one of the the column names. Please post the column definition using the DESC command. If there were spaces, you'd need to refer such column with quotes throughout your code, which is not really ideal to use. Oracle does not recommend quoted identifiers, so please do not allow space in column names. Please use an alias to identify the column name in the select statement and also use consistent column names throughout the query. This will help in code maintenance and better readability of code.

Below is a small piece of code i tried for your reference.

```
-- Create tables
CREATE TABLE customer(
"customer code" VARCHAR2(10),
"customer name" VARCHAR2(50),
address         VARCHAR2(100),
postcode        VARCHAR2(10),
telephone       VARCHAR2(10));


CREATE TABLE contract(
"contract no"     VARCHAR2(10), 
"customer code"   VARCHAR2(10), 
"start date"      DATE,
"end date"        DATE
);

-- Populate values
INSERT INTO customer
values ('4188','Mrs Alma Levy','"Ap #739-3930"','FA93 6JF','0000000000');

INSERT INTO contract
VALUES('08/4469','4188','15-DEC-2008','14-DEC-2009');

-- Query data
SELECT con."contract no", cust."customer code", con."start date", con."end date"
FROM contract con
INNER JOIN customer cust
ON con."customer code" = cust."customer code";

OUTPUT:
contract no   customer code  start dat end date 
------------- -------------- --------- ---------
08/4469       4188           15-DEC-08 14-DEC-09
```

Also see another version of this query without spaces in column names in your another question 'Support with sql join statement' :)

Happy Coding

HTH